# Edits to an Answer by the OP

Tags: discussion

I gave an answer for this question

[What's the meaning of "be broker than the Ten Commandments"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167526/whats-the-meaning-of-be-broker-than-the-ten-commandments/167532#167532)

It appears that the questioner edited my answer. That seems odd. Is there a way for me to see how the questioner altered my answer? Is there a way for me to eliminate that edit if I do not agree with it? Are there formal rules or informal norms about who may edit another's answer?

Comment: There is more information on editing in the help center: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/editing and some detailed information on suggested edits in an FAQ post on the main StackExchange meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/273494

Answer (score 2):

Your answer had a typo. The OP fixed it. They didn't change anything important to the answer. You can see the edit history of a post by simply clicking on the "edited [timeframe]" above the name of the person who submitted the edit. In your case, that takes you to [this page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/167532/revisions).

If you disagree with any edit, regardless of who submitted it, you can click the "rollback" button on that same page to revert it to an earlier version of the post.

[image: Rollback link circled on an edit history page]

This site and the network it belongs to is community edited. There are no rules for who can submit edits. Even anonymous, unregistered users can. We send all edit suggestions by users with less than 2000 reputation to an edit queue for review by the other users on the site (this edit was approved through that process).

Comment: Also, authors should be notified of suggested edits that are going through the approval queue, and can cast a binding vote to apply or reject those edits.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. They completely respond to what I wanted to know.